# In R - Error: could not find function "R2" or "RMSE" but caret package is loaded

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to call the RMSE and R2 functions in the caret package per the book Applied Predictive Modeling (page 100) but I an get error saying they are not found:

> Error: could not find function "R2"
>   Error: could not find function "RMSE"

This are how I am making the calls:

```
> R2(predicted,observed)
Error: could not find function "R2"
> RMSE(predicted,observed)
Error: could not find function "RMSE"
> library(caret)
> help(R2)
```

I've got the package loaded as shown in the screenshot. [image]

I also didn't find it [here](http://search.r-project.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=RMSE%20KUHN&max=100&result=normal&sort=score&idxname=functions) using RSiteSearch call:

```
RSiteSearch("RMSE",restrict="function")
```

Are these functions no longer part of the package? I don't see them explicitly called at the [caret site](http://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html#model-specific-metrics) either

Thanks

Comment: Have you called `library(caret)` before calling `R2(predicted,observed)`?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I have followed the pertinent steps listed in the question that is considered a duplicate of this. I am asking if a specific function is still present in a specific package, despite the documentation in the book which is generating an error. I feel I have done the due diligence to ask the question. I can event get help(R2) to work but still get the error.

Comment: Have you read the comment?